# A map in which every country has three sides is 3-colourable

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to prove that a map in which every country has three sides is 3-colourable unless it is a copy of $K_4$.

That $K_4$ is not 3-colourable is clear because the planar complete graph $K_4$ contains $4$ triangles is therefore not 3-colourable, but what about the first part of the statement. Is this somehow a simple conclusion from the 4 colour theorem?

Comment: Do you mean "unless it contains a copy of $K_4$"?

Comment: You mean "is a planar embedding of $K_4$"?

Comment: Yes, unless it contains a copy of $K_4$.

Comment: How can it containa copy of $K_4$ without being $K_4$? Or are we talking about the *dual* groah, where the countries are vertices, not faces?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You're right, it can't (assuming it's connected) because of the requirement that every country has three sides.  So never mind my comment.

Comment: With "map in which country has three sides" I mean every "triangulated plane map", this might be a better expression.If the triangulated plane map is $K_4$ than it is not 3-colourable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up Brooks' theorem.

Comment: I am familiar with Brooks Theorem but how I can use it here?

Comment: Ah, I think  I see what you mean, we consider a simple connected graph which is not a complete grpah with the largest vertex degree 3, therefore G has to be 3-colourable unless it is K_4. This is exactly what Brooks Theorem says, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it.